# ASP.NET MVC / JavaScript - Decode Encoded HTML String from C# amper

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to access a static piece of HTML from JavaScript.  Here is what I am doing:

In _Header.cshtml:

```
@{
    string HTMLContent = @Server.HtmlDecode("&lt;div&gt;Hello World&lt;/div&gt;");
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var StaticHTML = @HTMLContent;
</script>
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

When I step through it does appear that the HTMLContent variable is being printed in JavaScript as if it were Unencoded.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When razor executes the code in your view, `@` will encode the value of your C# expression. So you want to avoid doing that. You may use `Html.Raw` method which does not do any html encoding.

Since you are assigning the value to the js variable, you should wrap it in quotes(single or double).

This should work.

```
var StaticHTML = "@Html.Raw(HTMLContent)";
console.log(StaticHtml);
```